# What does Kakashi's Anbu mask represent?

Tags: naruto

In the Anbu, the people have to wear masks. I was wondering what Kakashi's mask represented. To me it looks like a cat, but other people say it looks like a fox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kakashi Hatake's Anbu mask resembled a dog's face with red and black markings around the eyes, sides, and mouth.

Source:[Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake)

[image]

[image: This will help you differntiate between a dog, cat and fox.]

This will help you differntiate between a cat, fox and dog

Comment: That looks nothing like a dog.

Comment: it`s a dog . . .
you know just to keep a dog themed ninja going. . .
it would be funny seeing cat masked ninja summoning a horde of dog though

Comment: @NamikazeSheena well I guess that makes more sense..... kind of.